# Two physical servers, one domain

Tags: iis, web

I currently have an IIS server hosting my website (www.example.com).
I've just set up my raspberry pi and I've got this hosted as a website that can be accessed through the local IP which is Apache.

However, How do I make this public through my domain, but separate from my IIS server? So for example `rasp.example.com` allows me to go through my pi, but example.com goes through my IIS server?

I've got DNS set up through goDaddy btw.

Comment: Is your question how to create two DNS records using goDaddy? Or how to first push pages to a staging environment and later to a production environment?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new A record in the zone file in GoDaddy for rasp.example.com and set it to the IP of your raspberry pi.  You can set it to the private IP, but you will only be able to access it from within your local network.

If you want your raspberry pi apache to be public, then you have to know the public IP of your internet (Google "what is my ip") and you'll ALSO have to setup your firewall to forward traffic on port 80 over to the internal IP of your raspberry pi.